# Prove by Contradiction that the set of Positive Multiples of 11 is Infinite

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As the titles reads, I need to prove the set of positive multiples of 11 is infinite by contradiction.

I thought I'd start out by assuming the set of multiples is finite up to $k$ but I am unsure of how to proceed.

Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Hi! What did you try so far?

Comment: As I said above, I've really got no idea of where to start.

Comment: assume that $k$ is the 'largest' in the set, then $k=11m$ for some integer $m$. What's next?

Answer (score 1):

The set of positive multiples of $11$ can be put in bijection with the set of positive numbers, simply by dividing by $11$. If the former is finite, so is the latter. Can you prove, by contradiction, that there are infinitely many positive numbers?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If the set is infinite, it has a maximum element. If you can find a larger multiple of $11$, you found a contradiction.

Comment: Like in induction? ie. $k + 1$

Comment: @IamaTerribleProgrammer Even simpler. If $m$ is the largest element of the set $\{x\in\mathbb N| 11|x\}$, then you can construct $m'>m$ such that $11|m'$ and you are done.

Comment: What do you mean when you say $m′$?

Comment: @IamaTerribleProgrammer I mean if I give you a number $m$ which is divisible by $11$, you can construct some number $m'$ which is also divisible by $11$ and is larger than $m$.

Comment: So to construct $m'$ would it then be correct to say $m' = m+x: x\in R$

Comment: @IamaTerribleProgrammer No. The way you wrote it, $m'$ is not a number. Also, no offence, but you are obviously very very new in mathematics, to the point where I doubt a site like this can really help you. You need to talk to your teacher or your classmates about how to solve this kind of question. It will be much better for you than reading comments and answers here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29226/discussion-between-i-am-a-terrible-programmer-and-5xum).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  Take a look at Euclid's [Proposition IX:21](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIX/propIX21.html).  For "even," think "multiple of $11$."

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the set S of all positive multiples of 11 is finite. Let W be the number of digits in base 10 of the largest element in your set S.

Now, there is a number with more than W digits that you can construct as follows: N = 1111111111............11111, where you put W+1 or W+2 digits depending on the parity of W: if W is even you take W+2, if it is odd you take W+1. Observe that N has an even number of digits. Then the number N has more than W digits, therefore it is not in S. But on the other hand N is divisible by 11, as can be seen either by using the well-known criteria (alternate sum of digits gives 0 and 0 is divisible by 11) or directly by computing N/11 = 1010101......01 (with total number of digits being of course one less than that of N). So you get a contradiction, N is not in S but it has to be in S.

Answer (score 0):

There are, of course, many other ways to proceed. Perhaps a nice way is just to imitate what Euclid's did to prove that there are infinitely many primes, I mean the very first part of the argument, with a slight change: he supposes his set is finite, then multiply all of its members, add 1 to the product, and then proceeds with his proof. Your case is simpler: If the set S of all positive multiples of 11 is finite, just consider the product P of all of its members (you don't have to add 1). Then it is easy to prove that P is larger than any member of S, because S has at least 2 elements both larger than 1 (I am thinking in 33 and 55) and then the product of all of them is larger than each of them (because 33 x > x and 55 x > x for any positive x, and so on). On the other hand, P is divisible by 11 (because divisibility is transitive, i.e., a multiple of a multiple of 11 is a multiple of 11), so since it is too big to be in S you get your contradiction "à la Euclids".